# SOAUP UI- Assertion is getting failed

Tags: rest, soapui, soap-client

My API Response is below. I am trying put an assertion on id field:

[
{
"id": "10008709",
"label": "signal"
},
{
"id": "10014720",
"label": "Application"
},
{
"id": "10014721",
"label": "erver"
},
{
"id": "10014724",
"label": "Mandora"
}
]

My assertion is .id[0] should be equal to 10008709 but assertion is getting failed with below message :ASSERTION FAILED -> Comparison failed for path [.id[0]], expecting [10008709], actual was [[]].

Please could you help. Thanks in advance

Just to add if it helps. when I tried .id  it returns me [[10008709, 10014720, 10014721, 10014724]]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing the wrong thing.  id[0] is the entry you want, but by using the square brackets, you're saying id is an array and you want the first id in the array.  You don't.  You want the id from the first entry....

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

// I had to use JSON Slurper purely to create a demo JSON object to use as an example.
def slurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper();
def jsonString = '[ { "id": "10008709", "label": "signal" }, { "id": "10014720",     "label": "Application" }, { "id": "10014721", "label": "erver" }, { "id": "10014724", "label": "Mandora" } ]';
def result = slurper.parseText(jsonString);

// Let's get the first entry.
log.info(result[0]);

//Let's get the id for the first entry
log.info(result[0].id);

// Let's try an assertion.
assert "10008709" == result[0].id;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris for your reply. I really appreciate it. Please could you suggest how can i achieve above stesp  (which u explained using groovy)using SOAP UI assert window(please check screenshot)

Comment: Try [0].id  The difficult bit is not seeing the whole response.  For example, if your response is in data, the try data[0].id